# An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension ? How can I resolve this in my SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In my SQL Server Management Studio, any time I pick my table to the editor, I get this error:

> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension

I have tried to restart the system and this error msg keep popping out and freeze my editor .

An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension

To run my query as normal, without this error msg

Comment: What do you mean by 'every time I pick my table to the editor'? Can you be more specific and tell us step by step what are you doing?

Comment: If I want to select a table from my database ,the error will come up

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling SSMS.

Comment: Pls WHY do you suggest reinstalling SSMS ( I have the 2018 version)

Comment: because this error makes no sense. Meaning it can't be replicated and most probably it is due to a broken dll. Therefore a clean install should resolve your issue. However, this is just a suggestion and the first step I would take in troubleshooting it.

Comment: I will give it a try..and Update you .many Thanks

Comment: I get the same thing along with others. It happens in both 18.0 and 18.1. It happens when you try to drag the table name from Object Explorer into the editor window. Since version 18 I have never been able to do it. Old habit, but it will lock up SSMS and you have to hard-close the app in Task Manager.

Comment: what i did, was to install a lower version(17.9) and move on